# How to handle enums as arguments for public functions?

Tags: solidity, invalid-opcode

Assume this simple contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.3;

contract InvalidOpcode {

    enum Dir {UP, LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT}
    Dir public currentDir;

    function changeDir(Dir newDir) public {
        require(uint8(newDir) <= uint8(Dir.RIGHT), "Out of range");
        currentDir = newDir;
    } 

}
```

The exposed interface of the function accepts an uint8 as argument.
When run on Remix with a value of 4 (or greater) as the input, the tx will throw with this error:

```
transact to EnumTest.changeDir errored: VM error: invalid opcode.
invalid opcode  
    The execution might have thrown.
    Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Debugging reveals that the require statement is not reached (and is thus useless). The invalid opcode occurs while accesing the argument. The debugger shows the local variable `newDir: INVALID_ENUM<4> enum`.
I think the transaction then throws and stops using gas, but I am not sure!

When I run the same thing in a truffle environment, the transaction will exit with `status 0`.
`truffleAssert.fails(instance.changeDir(4),"status 0")` will catch it, but **all gas will be consumed in the transaction!** From what I know, it is not possible to debug further (on opcode level) in truffle.

My questions are:

1. Does this transaction indeed consume all gas?
2. If so, is there a way to prevent this?
3. Is there a way to revert the transaction with a meaningful message?
4. **What is the best practice to expose an Enum argument to the public interface?**

Edit:

One way to potentially solve the problem is to change the argument to an uint8:

```
contract FixedInvalidOpcode {

    enum Dir {UP, LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT}
    Dir public currentDir;

    function changeDir(uint8 newDir) public {
        require(newDir <= uint8(Dir.RIGHT), "Out of range");
        currentDir = Dir(newDir);
    } 

}
```

This behaves as expected. But is the type conversion `Dir(newDir)` safe and is this the recommended way to expose the function?

I would still like to get into what is happening if an enum is directly exposed to the interface and if that is something that can be improved in the compiler. In my opinion, the first contract above should revert with a failing assert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`enum Dir {UP, LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT}` corresponds to `uint8` values 0, 1, 2 and 3.

This explains why passing a value greater than 3 should cause some form of error.

That said, `require(false condition)` returns REVERT opcode, not INVALID opcode.

The latter is typically the result of either one of the following:

- `assert(x)` where `x` evaluates to `false`
- `arr[i]`, where `i >= arr.length`

Perhaps solc 0.6.x handles illegal enum values in the same manner.

I would sincerely doubt that, because REVERT opcode (`require`/`revert`) is logically designated for incorrect user input, while INVALID opcode (`assert`) is not.

So I recommend that you check if the error is not due to something outside of your contract (for example, something in your Remix setup).

**UPDATE:**

OK, it seems to be the case even in older compiler versions (tested 0.4.21).

Here is the relevant assembly code:

```
    tag_10:
      ...
      0x3     // maximum permitted value
      dup2    // load to register
      gt      // check greater than
      iszero  // if not, then ...
      tag_12
      jumpi   // ... jump to the tag (skip the next instruction)
      invalid // trigger INVALID opcode
    tag_12:
      ...
```

The good news on your side are that since the compiler handles illegal enum values, you can safely remove the `require` statement, because this verification is implicitly conducted for you at the very beginning of the function.

Comment: I agree with your assessment! I used a fresh remix environment and put nothing more than the code pasted above in there. It should be very easy to replicate.

Comment: @Newti: Check to see if it works fine when you downgrade to solc 0.4.25 for example.

Comment: @Newti: And BTW, if solc 0.6.x indeed handles illegal enum values, then it means that you can safely remove the `require` statement, as this verification is implicitly conducted for you. I find it odd that those guys at solc would use INVALID instead of REVERT, because it essentially means that the caller would pay more gas (plus, INVALID opcode is not designated for incorrect user input, while REVERT opcode is designated exactly for that).

Comment: I tested with a few older solc versions (including 0.4.25) and got the same INVALID opcode every time. I agree that it should REVERT instead. Letting the compiler handle it (and removing the require) sounds like the cleaner solution than converting ints to enums. So the question now is why solc does not use REVERT...

Comment: @Newti: I'm pretty sure that solc 0.4.x does not apply this assertion on enum values, and if I'm right, then it implies that the INVALID opcode is due to something else in your code or in your setup. I don't see anything that could trigger this error in the code, so I suspect that this issue is related to your setup.

Comment: I am able to replicate it in different environments (truffle, remix, cli) with the same results, using solc 0.4.2x. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but to me it looks like solc is using INVALID for verifying enums.

Comment: @Newti: Hmmm, that simplifies thing. Let me check it on Truffle.

Comment: @Newti: See my update to the answer.

Comment: To chime in here, with the require statement removed, the TX still burns the full amount of gas if the value is outside the range of the enum.

Comment: @Nick: You're right, but that behavior is embedded in the compiler's output, so I can't see much that you can do with it (except for manually editing the byte-code and replacing every INVALID opcode with a REVERT opcode).

Answer (score 2):

Enum can be safely used as an input to external functions, but (as discussed earlier) throws `panic` instead of `error` if the uint8 value is out of scope.

You can take a look into docs https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.8/control-structures.html?highlight=panic%20error#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require and find out that `0x21` error code is dedicated to enum conversions.

From one point of view, it's an input issue, from another it is us trying to convert a value to enum that is out of scope. That is probably the reason why it's not considered an input issue.